In BIRD , Duplicate Routing Entries for the Same Network
My server is using Bird to get routing from the top switch. ( it has ecmp arch)
# birdc s route protocol routing1
BIRD 1.6.3 ready.
0.0.0.0/0         via 10.171.1.2 on p1  ! (100) 
10.171.10.0/24    via 10.171.1.2 on p1  * (100) 
10.171.11.0/24    via 10.171.1.2 on p1  * (100)
10.171.12.0/24    via 10.171.1.2 on p1  * (100) 
10.171.13.0/24    via 10.171.1.2 on p1  * (100) 

# birdc s route protocol routing2
BIRD 1.6.3 ready.
0.0.0.0/0         via 10.171.2.2 on p2  ! (100) 
10.171.10.0/24    via 10.171.2.2 on p2  * (100) 
10.171.11.0/24    via 10.171.2.2 on p2  * (100)
10.171.12.0/24    via 10.171.2.2 on p2  * (100) 
10.171.13.0/24    via 10.171.2.2 on p2  * (100) 


I changed Top switch's LP value to make traffic flows as a one path.

Revert Lp Vvlue to Original value.

In some nodes, Duplicate Routings are created


# ip ro
 
10.171.10.0/24 proto bird
        nexthop via 10.171.1.2 dev p1 
        nexthop via 10.171.2.2 dev p2 
10.171.10.0/24 proto bird metric 32
        nexthop via 10.171.1.2 dev p1
        nexthop via 10.171.2.2 dev p2

I guess this issue occurs because new routes are being received without updating the existing routes.
I would like to verify this and seek advice from anyone who has experienced this phenomenon

Did you enable merge paths in your kernel protocol? If yes - try disabling.

i'm using that option for ecmp.
there are two top switch that connected with server.
as your comment, this option can be problem.
thank you for your advice
